# Bug with odd columns in table in a database structure Access

Tags: database, debugging, ms-access, ms-access-2010, database-schema

I have table called `money` which 5 columns (3 of columns `ve been deleted), in that we can be  assured by looking it structure or calling simple query:

```
select *
from money;
```

But then I look in the database structure that table has 8 columns. How can I fix this bug?

I tried to reopen, save Access - nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is a linked table from a server database.
The table structure is stored in your Access frontend, and isn't automatically updated when the backend structure changes.
To update:

Manually: delete the linked table, and link it again.

Automatically: look at TableDef.RefreshLink()